# Clob with inappropriate charset

Tags: oracle, file, character-encoding, clob

I want to load a file into plsql clob variable and then perform some regexp transformations on it. The problem I have is that somehow I get my charset messed up.

So far I tried:

```
declare 
 l_filename varchar2(100) := 'sample.txt';
 l_clob clob;
 l_bfile bfile;
 begin
 dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_clob, true);
 l_bfile := bfilename( 'SAMPLE_DIR', l_filename );
 dbms_lob.fileopen( l_bfile );
 dbms_lob.loadfromfile( l_clob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ));
 dbms_lob.fileclose( l_bfile );
 dbms_output.put_line(l_clob);
 end;
/
```

I created a flat file 'sample.txt' with 'test file' in it and when I'm eventually printing it I get '瑥獴⁦楬攊'. The charset I use in my db is utf-8. Why did my encoding got messed up?

I found some online encoder https://www.urlencoder.org/.
When I put my Chinese letters in it and used UTF16-BE as a destination charset I got 'test%20file%0A'. But I still don't know why my encoding got messed up.

Comment: When I run `file -i sample.txt' on my linux machine, the charset I get is 'charset=us-ascii'.

Comment: How do you create (and save) the file?

Comment: Looking at the docs, `loadfromfile` doesn't do any charset conversion, it just loads the binary file directly into the clob. You could try using `loadclobfromfile` instead, maybe with bfile_csid=1 (for us7ascii). The docs also suggest using sql*loader to load text files to clobs instead. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i998778

Comment: Wow! You are right. Changing ' dbms_lob.loadfromfile( l_clob, l_bfile, dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ));' to this ' dbms_lob.loadclobfromfile(l_clob,l_bfile,dbms_lob.getlength( l_bfile ),dest_off,src_off,0,lang_ctx,warning);
' makes text readable again. But why was there charset conversion in the case of loadfromfile? I had clob and not nclob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you **sure** your db character set is AL32UTF8 and your file on disk is ASCII? Because it looks like something, somewhere is AL16UTF16 (which I think is the same as UTF-16BE).

Your test string "test file\n" encodes to UTF8 bytes 0x746573742066696C650A. You actually have **5** Asian characters because the third is a non-printable character, LEFT-TO-RIGHT ISOLATE.

When I convert "test file\n" to UTF16, I get the following:

```
select dump( utl_i18n.raw_to_char( hextoraw('746573742066696C650A'), 'AL16UTF16' ), 1016 ) 
from dual;

Typ=1 Len=15 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: e7,91,a5,e7,8d,b4,e2,81,a6,e6,a5,ac,e6,94,8a

select dump( '瑥獴⁦楬攊', 1016) from dual;

Typ=96 Len=15 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: e7,91,a5,e7,8d,b4,e2,81,a6,e6,a5,ac,e6,94,8a
```

Note that the byte sequences are the same. The second `dump()` has `Typ=96`, which is an `NCHAR` value. Do you get the same character sets for your database as mine?

```
select * from nls_database_parameters 
where parameter IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET' );

PARAMETER               VALUE
NLS_CHARACTERSET        AL32UTF8
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
```

Comment: To be honest, so far I didn't know about NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET at all. I thought that every text that I'm dealing with is in NLS_CHARACTERSET. You are right. 'select * from nls_database_parameters(…)' returns 'AL16UTF16' for NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET and 'UTF8' for NLS_CHARACTERSET. But I still don't understand why such conversion occured. Did 'loadfromfile' function decided that it will switch to NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET?